# Can't figure out how to charge taxes

Tags: paypal

I have set up the sales tax in my account but Paypal always return 0%

Here are the `SetExpressCheckout` parameters

[image]

This is the result

```
TOKEN=EC-03E58022CK445842R
&TIMESTAMP=2015-01-10T20:48:57Z
&CORRELATIONID=b875a01d29414
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=119
&BUILD=14726230
```

Then the user is redirected to Paypal and enter its billing address.

On the callback url, I do the `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` with the following parameters

[image]

and the result is

```
 TOKEN=EC-5TF12550CK165913F
&BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS=0
&CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionNotInitiated
&TIMESTAMP=2015-01-10T21:04:05Z
&CORRELATIONID=7eefa2e1b98b5
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=119
&BUILD=14726230
&EMAIL=something@hotmail.com
&PAYERID=WDUJK7NL59J7A&PAYERSTATUS=verified
&FIRSTNAME=SandboxTest
&LASTNAME=Account
&COUNTRYCODE=CA
&CURRENCYCODE=CAD
&AMT=59.99
&SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
&HANDLINGAMT=0.00
&TAXAMT=0.00
&INSURANCEAMT=0.00
&SHIPDISCAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=CAD
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=59.99
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=false
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS=None
&PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE=0
```

so the sales tax are not calculated

and from the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) it looks like you have to set up the taxes yourself `SetExpressCheckout` with `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMTm`

but how are you supposed to know how much to charge if you don't know where the user lives?

Comment: Is your user in the same region that sales tax should apply to?

Comment: The user is from Ontario and I have 5% sales tax for Canada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call `SetExpressCheckout` and redirect the user to PayPal, they'll login and review the order, choose their shipping, etc. and are then sent back to the ReturnURL you specified.

That is where you'll call `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` like you did, which would typically contain the payer's shipping address.  You could then calculate shipping and tax based on that address and display a final review page to your buyer which includes all of the totals.

Note that your GECD response doesn't include an address because you specified NOSHIPPING=1 in your SEC request.

When they submit that final review you'll call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, and make sure to include the shipping and tax parameters in that request in order for them to be included in the payment that gets processed at that point.

If you want to skip your own final review page, you can setup a callback service where PayPal's review page will POST the payer details to a script you have sitting on your server, which can then take the address, calculate shipping and tax values, and return them back to PayPal's review page, which populates a drop down on that page so the payer can choose from the rates your script returns.  They call this the [Instant Update API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer but I added the noshopping option because it's a only a subscription.  There's no shipping. At first I thought I could calculate the sales tax like this but I noticed there's no billing address

Comment: Right, so your options are to go ahead and include shipping simply for that reason, or keep shipping out, but add a field to your checkout for the user to input their zip code.  You could look this up in a zip code db or something so that you can then calculate their tax and add it accordingly.  If you do this, then you could include it in the SEC request so that it shows up on the PayPal review page, and then you wouldn't need your additional review page.

Comment: Thank you Andrew but when the sales tax configured in PayPal are supposed to work? I used to have a standard subscription button but they told me it wasn't supported and that I have to use a express checkout button.

Comment: Not with Express Checkout. With Express Checkout you have to handle all the tax and shipping calculations and include them in your requests.  It will not use any profile settings.

Comment: Is there a way to split the sales tax? For federal and provincial? thank you

Comment: PayPal only provides a single tax parameter.  If you need to split it up you'll have to do that within your own system.

Comment: When I set TAXAMT in the SetExpressCheckout, the TAXAMT is still 0 in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails. Is it normal? Also is AMT is the total with the sales tax or without? thank you

Comment: NVM I had to use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT. Thank you